# Scoring multiple TRUES in Pythton RE Search

Tags: regex, python-3.x, loops, python-re

**Background**

I have a list of "bad words" in a file called bad_words.conf, which reads as follows
(I've changed it so that it's clean for the sake of this post but in real-life they are expletives);

```
wrote (some )?rubbish
swore
```

I have a user input field which is cleaned and striped of dangerous characters before being passed as `data` to the following script, score.py
(for the sake of this example I've just typed in the value for `data`)

```
import re

data = 'I wrote some rubbish and swore too'

# Get list of bad words
bad_words = open("bad_words.conf", 'r')
lines = bad_words.read().split('\n')
combine = "(" + ")|(".join(lines) + ")"

#set score incase no results
score = 0

#search for bad words
if re.search(combine, data):
    #add one for a hit
    score += 1

#show me the score
print(str(score))
bad_words.close()
```

Now this finds a result and adds a score of 1, as expected, without a loop.

**Question**

I need to adapt this script so that I can add 1 to the score every time a line of "bad_words.conf" is found within text.
So in the instance above, `data = 'I wrote some rubbish and swore too'` I would like to actually score a total of 2.

1 for "wrote some rubbish" and +1 for "swore".

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

Changing `combine` to just:

```
combine = "|".join(lines)
```

And using [`re.findall()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.findall):

```
In [33]: re.findall(combine,data)
Out[33]: ['rubbish', 'swore']
```

---

The problem with having the multiple capturing groups as you originally were doing is that `re.findall()` will return each additional one of those as an empty string when one of the words is matched.